# ASP.Net Web Handler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax, httphandler

What is the advantage of Managed Handler over normal .ashx web Handler?

What will be the best option for a performance critical application?

1. Asp.Net Synchronous Web Handler
2. Asp.Net Asynchronous Web Handler

For a multiple concurrent request handling application such as an Image managing application what handler will be the best option? Synchronous,Asynchronous or Managed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, both synchronous and asynchronous handlers authored in .NET are managed handlers. "Managed" is only a term used in context of IIS, which can use handlers written in native, unmanaged code as well as managed.

As to which you should use, it depends. It will come down to the nature of the work the handler performs, and concurrent user load. If you have a large number of concurrent users with a reasonable amount of IO, database, processing, or external service calls, then async can yield performance gains. Similarly, a small number of concurrent users can still benefit in the event the handler performs long-running, heavy IO or other processing. However, you wouldn't automatically just assume the worst (high user concurrency) and immediately set in on an async handler. They are more complicated to author, debug, and maintain.